# Given $n$ arbitrary points, generate a function that passes through all points, with the line (or arc) between two points resembling a straight line

Tags: calculus, finitely-generated, fixed-points

I was wondering one day, say there were $n$ arbitrary points. Label the points $\{(x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2), (x_3, y_3),…, (x_n, y_n)\}$ All the points have a unique x-value.

For simplicity, let’s say that the x-values aren’t too spaced out from each other, and that the differences between x-values are the same. Let the spacing between each x-value be $v_x$.

I would like to generate a function that passes through all the points, with the line (or arc) between two points most resembling a straight line.

This means that, between points, there shouldn’t be any excessive wiggles that ‘mess up’ the graph in any way. It should be ‘smooth’. As an addition, I want this function to wiggle up and down smoothly forever, not like a polynomial that zooms off to infinity, so some trigonomic waves should be used instead of polynomials. Unless, there’s another type of function that wiggles up and down that I don’t know about.

I first thought of using Taylor and Maclaurin series, but realized that I didn’t have any function to take the derivative of. Also, the result would be polynomials, which zoomed off to infinity.

I then tried combining a few trigonomic functions in Desmos. That didn’t work too well either, since these were approximations and didn’t quite go through the points exactly.

I also read a few other questions on this topic, but only found either:

1. Generic formulas that only gave me a vague sense of what I was supposed to do
2. Articles that were a bit too hard to understand
3. Polynomials.

Write the function as f(x). Use the variables $v_x$ and $n$. If sigma notation is used, write the x and y coordinates of the points as $x_i$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be worth a try. Choose some number $d$ comparable in size to $x_n-x_1$. Let $$f(x)=a_1\sin(x/d)+a_2\sin(2x/d)+\cdots+a_n\sin(nx/d)$$ Then the equations $$y_i=a_1\sin(x_i/d)+a_2\sin(2x_i/d)+\cdots+a_n\sin(nx_i/d),\qquad i=1,2,\dots n$$ give you $n$ linear equations in the $n$ unknowns $a_1,\dots,a_n$.

Comment: Hi, I’m just a seventh grader, so please forgive me if this answer is obvious, but what are the variables $a_1,…,a_n$? Anyways, thanks for the answer!

Comment: I have corrected some typos in my answer. Suppose your points were $(1,2)$ and $(2,7)$, and suppose we take $d=2$. Then we get the equations $2=a_1\sin(1/2)+a_2\sin(1)$ and $7=a_1\sin(1)+a_2\sin(2)$. You solve that system of two linear equations in the two unknowns $a_1$ and $a_2$, and then you stick those values into the equation $f(x)=a_1\sin(x/d)+a_2\sin(2x/d)$, and that's your function. I'm not sure whether that's what you were asking.

Comment: By the way, the Terms of Service say, "You must be at least 13 years old to access or use the Network or Services, including without limitation to complete a Stack Overflow account registration. By accessing or using the Services or the Network in any manner, you represent and warrant that you are at least 13 years of age. If you are under 13 years old, you may not, under any circumstances or for any reason, access or use the Services or Network in any manner, and may not provide any personal information to or on the Services or Network (including, e.g., a name, address,  or email address)."

Comment: Ah! So the $a$ variables are constants! Thank you! By the way, I am thirteen years old. Just passed the requirements! I’ve marked your answer correct.